# getting certificate error on deploying application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-1.2

I built a website and then deploy it on the server. But when i open the url then i get the following error
[image: certificate Error]
But when i click on "Continue to this website" , then i get the following message
[image: https Error]

How can i get rid of both these messages. I mean when i open my website then it get open normally instead of first showing certificate error, and also how can i overcome the https error warning message.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of server you have?IIS?

Comment: @Peter Mensik We deployed it on Glass fish 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configured your server certificate correctly, the first message should disappear. In a development environment it should no bother you as long as it works in production.

Glassfish comes with an invalid certificate as default. You need to replace this by a valid one.

The second message indicates that you include content on your page that doesn't come over a secured connection (maybe an include/resource with the url `http://` instead of `https://`). Check if your included resources are delivered via https as well.

Comment: Thanks. But please can you tell me how can i configure my certificate to overcome the certificate error? I deployed my application on Glass Fish 2. And also how can i check whether i included resources using http:// instead oh https://? Thanks

Comment: I am not using GF 2. I could point give you some tips for GF3, but I think this wouldn't help you much. Try a web search instead. As to the second message: Check your browser source or use Firebug/Chrome dev tools. In Chrome there is a network tab in the devtools that shows all resources your page loads.

Comment: HHmm i found this link, is it what you are talking about ? link https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/using_ssl_with_glassfish_v2. Also the https message is only coming on IE. On fire fox it is not coming. I checked on firebug. Under Net, where you have options Images, Flash, Media. On firefox https error is not coming. Only IE is showing it. I am suing IE 8. How can i check https resources on IE 8. Thanks.

Comment: Sometime it can be a browser plugin that includes something. I once had problems with Google translator that included insecure resources.

Comment: ok but how can i check on IE 8 that what insecure resources my site is including when opening. Because i get this message on internal pages also.

Comment: Can you disable all or selected plugins?

Comment: Yes i did. By going to Tools->Manage add-ons->Show all add-ons and then i deselected all the add-ons but this https message is still coming. So i think this is not related to add-ons or plugins?

Comment: Then I don't know. Maybe you have a custom security configuration in IE? You could try it with a clean installation on a differen computer and check if the problem persists.

Comment: I think this https message is coming because of the certificate error because certificate tell IE about the encryption. As i have no valid certificate, that's why this https error is coming.